# How to write a non-equation word as a word

Tags: subscripts, characters

For preparing my CV using overleaf, I have to included a link which contains the word E_certificate

The output, without even enclosing the words between $ $ , prints the certificate as a subscript to E.

How can I just type E_certificate without it going subscript?

Comment: Welcome to TZeX.SE. Try `E\_certificate`.

Comment: as Zarko said, but is it really E_certificate not E-certificate?

Comment: I guess you could use `\textunderscore` aswell.